# How to find intersection points of lines?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Considering I have three functions

```
f1 = -x + 1;

f2 = x - 1;

f3 = x + 3;
```

How can I find the intersection points of this functions?
Thanks.

This didn't work

```
t = Solve[{k \[Element] f1, k \[Element] f2}, {k}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here it is an overkill but maybe for general context it is worth to say this.

It does not work because `fs` are not regions:

```
f1 = ImplicitRegion[{y == -x + 1}, {x, y}]
f2 = ImplicitRegion[{y == x - 1}, {x, y}]

Solve[{k \[Element] f1, k \[Element] f2}, {k}]
```

> ```
> {{k -> {1, 0}}}
> ```

I said an overkill because people usually do something like:

```
Solve[{y == -x + 1, y == x - 1}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1, y -> 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
Solve[{y == 1 - x, y == x - 1}, {x, y}]
Solve[{y == 1 - x, y == x + 3}, {x, y}]
```

seems the simplest approach. Another "overkill" region approach:

```
l1 = InfiniteLine[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
l2 = InfiniteLine[{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}];
l3 = InfiniteLine[{{0, 3}, {1, 4}}];
ri1 = RegionIntersection[l1, l2];
ri2 = RegionIntersection[l1, l3];
Reduce[RegionMember[ri1, {x, y}]]
Reduce[RegionMember[ri2, {x, y}]]
```

yield y == 0 && x == 1 and y == 2 && x == -1 respectively

Answer (score 6):

Use [Solve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) the neat way (and see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EquationSolving.html)):

```
Solve[{f1 == f2}, x]
{*
{x -> 1}
*}
Solve[{f1 == f3}, x]
{*
{x -> -1}
*}

Plot[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{1, 0}, {-1, 2}}]}]
```

[image]