# How to create a line due to requiriements?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, intersection

Considering we have three lines, and know the intersection points ([How to find intersection points of lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74150/how-to-find-intersection-points-of-lines/74153#74153))

How can I draw a line that will cross the intersection point of the two lines and will be parallel to the third line?

Thanks.

Comment: I consider that it always exists (like -x + 1, 2 x - 3 and 5 x - 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but a parallel line could look like and be constructed as follows.

The interesting points:

```
p1 = Plot[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{{1, 0}, {-1, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-3, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

And connected with a [InfiniteLine](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html)

```
infL = Graphics[InfiniteLine[{{-3, 0}, {-1, -2}}]];
Show[p1, infL]
```

[image]

Or you can find a [Fit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html):

```
p2 = {-1, -2};
p1 = {-3, 0};
MyFit = Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, x}, x] // Chop
```

> -3. - 1. x

and use it with Plot:

```
Plot[{f1, f2, f3, MyFit}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{1, 0}, {-1, 2}, p2, p1}]}]
```

[image]