# Finding the intersection of two graphs

Tags: equation-solving

I'm having difficulty with finding the intersecting point of two graphs. Here is what I have done so far:

```
Plot[{8*n^2, 64*n*Log2[n]}, {n, 0, 100}]
```

which produces the following graph:

[image]

To find the intersection I tried:

```
FindRoot[{8*n^2, 64*n*Log2[n]}, {0, 100}, {0, 20000}]
```

But I got an error I think:

> FindRoot::nlnum1: "The function value {{8.\ n^2,92.3325\ n\ Log[n]}[0.,0.]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} when the arguments are {0.,0.}"

I am using Mathematica 10.

Comment: `Solve[8*n^2 - 64*n*Log2[n] == 0, n] // N`

Comment: I'm sorry, have you seen `FindRoot` documentation page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [74150](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74150/how-to-find-intersection-points-of-lines) or [28987](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28987/finding-intersection-of-two-graphs).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to set the first equation equal to the second and use `Reduce` to solve the system:

```
Block[{f1, f2, n, sol},
 f1 := 8*n^2;
 f2 := 64*n*Log2[n];
 sol = N@Reduce[f1 == f2, n]]
```

(* n == 1.1 || n == 43.5593 *)

Also, you might want to check out the Mathematica tutorials on [equation solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EquationSolving.html).