# Integral equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, integral-equations

So there is this equation that I have to numerically solve for T:

```
Q/(3nRT) = f(T/300) - f(T/77)
```

Here Q = 920.364, n = 0.24, R = 8.314 while f is defined as the following:

```
f[t_?NumericQ]:= (3/t^4)*NIntegrate[(y^3)/(E^y -1),{y,0,t}]
```

I'm trying to do the following based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79399/finding-the-intersection-of-two-graphs), (*Edited f2 here; initially was f[T/77]-f[T/300]*)

```
Block[{f1,f2,T,sol},
f1:= Q/(3nRT);
f2:= f[T/300]-f[T/77];
sol=N@Reduce[f1==f2,T]]
```

This is just giving errors:

```
Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help. >>
```

and I'm unable to solve for T. Please help! Is there any elegant method of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Q = 920.364;
n = 0.24;
R = 8.314;
f[t_?NumericQ] := 3/t^4*NIntegrate[y^3/(Exp[y] - 1), {y, 0, t}]

Plot[Evaluate[{Q/(3 n R T), f[T/77] - f[T/300]}], {T, 0, 10000}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Q/(3n R T)", "f[T/77]-f[T/300]"}]
```

[image]

There are no crossings. Your equation has not a real solution.

Edit with the new condition.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Q/(3 n R T), -f[T/77] + f[T/300]}], {T, 0, 2000}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Q/(3n R T)", "-f[T/77]+f[T/300]"}]
```

[image]

```
eq = Q/(3 n R T) == -f[T/77] + f[T/300];
FindRoot[eq, {T, 500}]
(* {T -> 470.293} *)
```

It looks much better now!

Comment: Oops that should be f[T/300]-f[T/77].

Comment: @Sunil S. Now the solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by **rewi** there is no solution.

Despite that I think it is beneficial to attack problems of this nature by evaluating the integral up front and then using it in downstream processing.

In other words, get rid of `NIntegrate` if possible.

For your example replace `NIntegrate` with `Integrate` and see if there is a symbolic result.

```
Integrate[(t^3)/(E^t - 1), t]

(* -(t^4/4) + t^3 Log[1 - E^t] + 3 t^2 PolyLog[2, E^t] - 
 6 t PolyLog[3, E^t] + 6 PolyLog[4, E^t] *)
```

Now evaluate that at `t=0`. In order to do that one has use `Limit` to avoid an indeterminate expression.

```
Limit[-(t^4/4) + t^3 Log[1 - E^t] + 3 t^2 PolyLog[2, E^t] - 
  6 t PolyLog[3, E^t] + 6 PolyLog[4, E^t], t -> 0]

(* π^4/15 *)
```

Now `f[t_]` can be defined as (side note, avoid capitol letters, `T` so as to not conflict with predefined Mathematica symbols).

```
f[t_] := (3/t^4)*(-(t^4/4) + t^3 Log[1 - E^t] + 
    3 t^2 PolyLog[2, E^t] - 6 t PolyLog[3, E^t] + 
    6 PolyLog[4, E^t] - π^4/15)
```

and use this in your analysis.